# Determine value of parameter in a generic enum without a switch

Tags: swift

This is my code:

```
public enum Result<T> {
    case succes(data: T), error(resultError: ResultError)

    // Is this possible without the switch?
    public var error: ResultError? {
        switch self {
        case .succes(_):
            return nil
        case .error(let resultError):
            return resultError
        }
    }
}

public enum ResultError: Int {
    case someError = -777
}
```

I want to know if there is someway to check if `self` can be conditionally casted to case `error` and return that value, otherwise return nil, without the switch.

I tried using the guard statement, but it failed:

```
guard let _error = self as? Result.error
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't forget there is the `if case` statement, which does pattern matching in an `if`-like style:

```
public var error: ResultError? {
    if case .error(let e) = self {
        return e
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

And there is nothing wrong with using a switch. I think it is perfectly fine and even more readable than `if case`.